# How to make an ArrayList inside a class and why like that?

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist, methods

I creating a simple game where I have a `User` class where I store user data. There is a specific kind of data that I want to store in a `ArrayList` and where I want to add things to during the game. Below you can see how I thought I had to write it, but apparently it is not correct like that. Why not? How do I do it correctly and why like that? I searched on the internet but couldn't find it.

```java
public Class User {
    List positions;
}
```

```java
User x = new User;
x.positions = new ArrayList;

x.positions.add(1);
x.positions.add(2);
```

Comment: You are not calling the constructor properly i.e. `new ArrayList`. You are missing the parenthesis.

Comment: Two things: A) please read [mcve] ... and in future questions, include information about the error you see ... but more importantly: B) dont expect people here to explain simply java syntax to you. Every character you put into your code does matter. So when you READ a tutorial, a book pay attention to all details. Not for example that your code leaves out the "generics" part of lists completely, normally you do things like `List<Coordinate> positions = new ArrayList<>();` for example.

Comment: In a class declaration the keyword "class" must be written with a lowercase c, as in `public class User {...}`.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should make positions private.
Second, you need to make the appropriate public getter and setter methods of the positions.

See some sample below:
Class User (package is omitted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {
    private List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    public void setPositions(List<Integer> positions) {
        this.positions = positions;
    }
}
```

Class Main (package is omitted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.getPositions().add(1);
        user.getPositions().add(2);

        // another way
        List<Integer> positions = user.getPositions();
        positions.add(3);

        // another way
        List<Integer> myNewList = new ArrayList<>();
        myNewList.add(4);
        myNewList.add(5);
        myNewList.add(6);
        // below will replace list 123 with 456
        user.setPositions(myNewList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: your answer is better than the one from Vicas, but still: what is the point of returning the list to client code? The idea of a good interface is to **hide** information. The second you have a getter for that list, and allow clients to directly update that list, you open a can of problems. Having getter/setters for the list is the wrong approach.

Comment: What you said is true. 

In the getPositions() it should be returning either 
(1) a copy of the list so that the original list won't get affected should the copy be manipulated. 
(2) an unmodifiable list so that the caller cannot change anything to the list

Comment: Why expose the list at all? The point of a good interface is to provide the needed functionality, not data structures. Dont create interfaces that give your client code something to work with - write the interface in a way so that it DOES what the client needs. Somehow related to the "tell dont ask" clean code principle.

Answer (score 1):

I would change `List` to `ArrayList<T>`, where `T` is a type of object, so it has a constraint of what can be stored in it. Also, in your class, you want to set it up so you have private variables, with setters and getters to access the variables.

I also included an initialzer block that constructs the ArrayList, and this initializer block gets called on every creation of a new User object, even if you have multiple constructors in the class. Without constructing the ArrayList, it would be null.

```java
public class User {
    private ArrayList<T> positions;

    public ArrayList<T> getPositions() {
        return this.positions;
    }

    public void setPosition(ArrayList<T> position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    // Initializer block
    {
        this.position = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

With this, you can then call `x.getPosition.add()` to add positions, view positions, remove positions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. Instantiate your `ArrayList` with a correct constructor (*at the moment, your code won't compile, as you are not calling the constructor. It should be `new ArrayList<T>();`*);
2. Define more specific granularity for your `List`, and declare it with a Generic type parameter, like `List<TypeYouWantToStore>`. Otherwise, your list is of the *raw type*, and will not have any constraint on what you store in it;
3. Define *accessors* (getters) and *mutators* (setters) for your `List` field, instead of accessing it directly as a `public` field. You'll then have:

   ```
   x.getPositions().add(1);
   ```
4. I'd initialize your `List` field, from the constructor of `User` class.